# how to get actual thread execution time in java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am trying to measure the time that a thread takes to execute.
I have created a sample programme

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

public class Sample {
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    ThreadPoolExecutor exec = (ThreadPoolExecutor)Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        exec.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("[Sample] Thread id : " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ", time : " + (end - start));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Each thread sleeps for 10 seconds. So the duration = (end - start) should be 10000. But some threads are taking more time than expected. I am guessing this also includes thread switching time and and blocking time. Is there a way to measure the exectution time in threaded programme in JAVA?

The thing is that I have a programme that makes network calls in threads. So even if the socket time out is say 60 seconds, the thread execution time is close to 2 minutes. My guess is that the above way of calculating execution time also accounts for thread switching time and blocking time. It is not measuring the actual thread execution time

Thanks.

Comment: Thread.sleep is not guaranteed to sleep exactly ten seconds. It sleeps at least ten seconds. Why don't you want to measure the actual execution time it takes? What exactly do you want to measure instead?

Comment: Hey! You have measured the execution time. Where's the problem?

Comment: @akuzminykh the thing is that I have a programme that makes network calls in threads. So even if the socket time out is say 60 seconds, the thread execution time is close to 2 minutes. My guess is that the above way of calculating execution time also accounts for thread switching time and blocking time. It is not measuring the actual thread execution time

Comment: You mean, you want to measure the time the thread is in running state? I don't think there is any way to measure that (precisely) from within the Java code itself.

Comment: @akuzminykh yes, the actual running time

Comment: I think, that you should show the code that is doing the network calls and ask why it is executing longer than you expect rather asking about threads. Please create another question if you would like to follow my advise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Measure java short time running thread execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664897/measure-java-short-time-running-thread-execution-time)

Answer (score 0):

For such cases I use [JavaVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html), it is a very very handy tool for finding concurrency issues.
I ran your code locally and this is what visual VM shows me.

All of the threads have exactly the same sleep time, so the differences we are seeing in the console log are probably misleading.

[image]